# Oracle - use CASE in WHERE and IN()

Tags: oracle, case, where-clause

Is it possible to have a `CASE IN()` clause in `WHERE` of Oracle?

For example:

```
SELECT vip 
FROM table 
WHERE
  CASE WHEN $inputVar LIKE '' 
  THEN vip IN (1,2,3)
  ELSE vip in ($inputVar)
  END
```

**Edit:** With this code I get the error:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: What is `$inputVar`?  Your query should probably just have an `OR` clause but if you are expecting to pass in a scalar variable that is a string with comma-separated values and have that evaluated as part of an `IN` list, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it with a subquery.

```
SELECT vip 
FROM table 
WHERE
vip in
 (select
  CASE WHEN $inputVar LIKE '' 
  THEN 1
  ELSE $inputVar
  END from dual)
```

But if you want the default value as multiple records seperated by comma, It cannot be done. You have to frame it dynamically.

Do it in query with help of union

```
select * from table where vip in (1,2,3) and $inputvar = ''
union all
select * from table where vip in $inputvar
```

Comment: This part fails
 WHERE vip IN (SELECT CASE WHEN '' LIKE '' THEN 1 ELSE 2,3,4 END FROM dual)
Edit: What does it mean to frame it dynamically? Sorry for the silly question. Please show an example. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot use stored procedure in my case. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: from table where vip in $inputvar - if $inputvar is empty string then Oracle would not execute the query...

Comment: Yes, thats why we have union all. the first query will execute in this case and return you default values. And in case of reverse first query will not return and any value and second query will.